# Extracting spectral indices from a cloud-masked image collection using the s2cloudless masking method

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I was implementing the cloud masking procedure from [the s2cloudless tutorial](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/tutorial_api_06) as recommended in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/445633/154274).

From the cloud-masked image collection, I wanted to extract some spectral indices, so I followed the structure of many other scripts and mapped a function over the image collection that applies `normalizeDifference` on each image.

This resulted in the following error: `AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'normalizeDifference'`.

I tried to verify whether it was due to the band names, but my request `s2_cl_corr.first().bandNames().getInfo()` was also answered with an error.

How can properly apply the spectral indices to the cloud-masked image collection?

```py
AOI = ee.Geometry.Point(-122.269, 45.701)
START_DATE = '2020-06-01'
END_DATE = '2020-09-01'
CLOUD_FILTER = 60
CLD_PRB_THRESH = 35
NIR_DRK_THRESH = 0.15
CLD_PRJ_DIST = 1
BUFFER = 50


def get_s2_sr_cld_col(aoi, start_date, end_date):
    # Import and filter S2 SR.
    s2_sr_col = (ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                 .filterBounds(aoi)
                 .filterDate(start_date, end_date)
                 .filter(ee.Filter.lte(
                     'CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', CLOUD_FILTER)))

    # Import and filter s2cloudless.
    s2_cloudless_col = (ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY')
                        .filterBounds(aoi)
                        .filterDate(start_date, end_date))

    # Join the filtered s2cloudless collection to the
    # SR collection by the 'system:index' property.
    return ee.ImageCollection(ee.Join.saveFirst('s2cloudless').apply(**{
        'primary': s2_sr_col,
        'secondary': s2_cloudless_col,
        'condition': ee.Filter.equals(**{
            'leftField': 'system:index',
            'rightField': 'system:index'
        })
    }))


def add_cloud_bands(img):
    # Get s2cloudless image, subset the probability band.
    cld_prb = ee.Image(img.get('s2cloudless')).select('probability')

    # Condition s2cloudless by the probability threshold value.
    is_cloud = cld_prb.gt(CLD_PRB_THRESH).rename('clouds')

    # Add the cloud probability layer and cloud mask as image bands.
    return img.addBands(ee.Image([cld_prb, is_cloud]))


def add_shadow_bands(img):
    # Identify water pixels from the SCL band.
    not_water = img.select('SCL').neq(6)

    # Identify dark NIR pixels that are not water
    # (potentially cloud shadow pixels).
    SR_BAND_SCALE = 1e4
    dark_pixels = (img.select('B8')
                   .lt(NIR_DRK_THRESH*SR_BAND_SCALE)
                   .multiply(not_water)
                   .rename('dark_pixels'))

    # Determine the direction to project
    # cloud shadow from clouds (assumes UTM projection).
    shadow_azimuth = (ee.Number(90)
                      .subtract(ee.Number(
                          img.get('MEAN_SOLAR_AZIMUTH_ANGLE'))))

    # Project shadows from clouds for
    # the distance specified by the CLD_PRJ_DIST input.
    cld_proj = (img.select('clouds')
                .directionalDistanceTransform(shadow_azimuth, CLD_PRJ_DIST*10)
                .reproject(**{'crs': img.select(0).projection(), 'scale': 100})
                .select('distance')
                .mask()
                .rename('cloud_transform'))

    # Identify the intersection of dark pixels with cloud shadow projection.
    shadows = cld_proj.multiply(dark_pixels).rename('shadows')

    # Add dark pixels, cloud projection, and identified shadows as image bands.
    return img.addBands(ee.Image([dark_pixels, cld_proj, shadows]))


def add_cld_shdw_mask(img):
    # Add cloud component bands.
    img_cloud = add_cloud_bands(img)

    # Add cloud shadow component bands.
    img_cloud_shadow = add_shadow_bands(img_cloud)

    # Combine cloud and shadow mask, set cloud and shadow as value 1, else 0.
    is_cld_shdw = (img_cloud_shadow
                   .select('clouds')
                   .add(img_cloud_shadow.select('shadows'))
                   .gt(0))

    # Remove small cloud-shadow patches and
    # dilate remaining pixels by BUFFER input.
    # 20 m scale is for speed, and assumes clouds don't require 10 m precision.
    is_cld_shdw = (is_cld_shdw
                   .focalMin(2)
                   .focalMax(BUFFER*2/20)
                   .reproject(**{'crs': img.select([0]).projection(),
                                 'scale': 20})
                   .rename('cloudmask'))

    # Add the final cloud-shadow mask to the image.
    return img.addBands(is_cld_shdw)


def apply_cld_shdw_mask(img):
    # Subset the cloudmask band and invert it so clouds/shadow are 0, else 1.
    not_cld_shdw = img.select('cloudmask').Not()

    # Subset reflectance bands and update their masks, return the result.
    return img.select('B.*').updateMask(not_cld_shdw)

def add_index_bands(img):
    # regular ndvi
    ndvi = img.normalizeDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI')

    # normalized difference red edge index
    ndrei = img.normalizeDifference(['B8', 'B5']).rename('NDREI')
    
    out_bands = ee.Image([ndvi, ndrei])

    return img.addBands(out_bands)


s2_cl_corr = (get_s2_sr_cld_col(AOI, START_DATE, END_DATE)
              .map(apply_cld_shdw_mask)
              .map(add_cld_shdw_mask))

s2_with_bands = s2_cl_corr.map(add_index_bands)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply misspelled the function's name.  It's [`normalizedDifference`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-normalizeddifference)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have used `normalizeDifference` when it should be `normalizedDifference`:

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-normalizeddifference